# JavaFX WebView - open links in system browser

Tags: java, javascript, webview, javafx

I'm using WebView for rendering both my own generated content and remote resources (like youtube videos) in iframes. I want the stuff I load into webview to load inside the view, while any links a user clicks should open in the system browser.

I tried to use the following link:
http://www.vg.no');" href="">test
but in java 1.8.0 it caused the JVM to crash, while in 1.8.0_05, it causes the content of
the webview to be cleared.

What is the correct way to to this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15555510/4773888