# JavaFX (2.2) loading a String from memory into a WebView

Tags: java, file, webview, javafx-2, href

I have to display some value with JavaFX (2.2) WebView. But value have to query form data base. This value may contain some reference to external web page and internal local file. How can make enable users to open those web pages and local files with WebView. Thanks.

```
  WebView wv = new WebView();
    wv.getEngine().setCreatePopupHandler(new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() {

        @Override
        public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures p) {
            Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
            WebView wv2 = new WebView();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(wv2));
            stage.show();
            return wv2.getEngine();
        }
    });

    String value = "<a href='http://stackoverflow.com' target='_blank'>Open a URL</a>" +
                      " <a href=\"file:///C:\\Users\\Dev\\debug.log\">Open a File</a> ";

    wv.getEngine().loadContent(value);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(wv);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got resolved this issue as following manner. For make this enable following stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555510/javafx-stop-opening-url-in-webview-open-in-browser-instead) was very helpful. Thanks.

```
    // Set HostService inherit from Application class 
    ServiceUtil.hostServices = getHostServices();

    // HTML code
    final String htmlCode = "<a href='http://stackoverflow.com ' target='_blank'>Open a Web URL</a>" +
                            "<a href=\"file:///C:\\Users\\Dev\\debug.log\">Open a Local File</a> ";

    // Create a WebView 
    final WebView webView = new WebView();        

    webView.getEngine().loadContent(htmlCode);

    webView.getEngine().locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, final String oldValue, final String newValue) {

                      if((newValue != null) && (!newValue.trim().equals(""))) {

                          Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                              @Override
                              public void run() {

                                  // Reset content as HTML codes
                                  // NB: This will make stop opening URL in WebView
                                  webView.getEngine().loadContent(htmlCode);

                                  // Direct URL to local browser
                                  ServiceUtil.hostServices.showDocument(newValue);
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  }
     });
```