# Why Document is null even after loadContent(...)? - (WebView JavaFx)

Tags: java, webview, javafx

Here is the simple code of MainController class initialize(...) method:

```
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.loadContent("<h1>hello</h1>"); // Successfully loaded on form
Document doc = webEngine.getDocument(); // null
```

Why *doc* is *null* and how to fix it?

Comment: Well, I tried, and solved it with a simple "Platform.runLater(() -> {Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();}" Now, This is the quick solution I found, there might be something else

Comment: It's solve problem with loadContent(), but don't solve by load(url) method. I don't understand why other people don't have this problem...

Comment: As stated in the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html you should add a listener to the loadworker, as loading might take time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I commented, you should add a listener, as loading takes time, to execute once the content is successfully loaded:

```
final WebView webView = new WebView();
final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
        Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
    }
});
webEngine.loadContent("<h1>hello</h1>");
//webEngine.load("http://google.ch"); // This works too
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the engine sets the document to null even after successful loading.
This usually happens with more complicated web pages.

The more reliable way to make sure that the document is not null is to use the property listener.

```
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

class MyClass {

    private WebView view = new WebView();
    private WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
    private Document document;

    MyClass() {
        engine.documentProperty().addListener((v, o, n) -> {
            if (n != null) {
                document = n;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I've lost a lot of time to solve this problem.
Here is my simple example which show text from textarea in the alert window by click on the button:

*index.html*

```
<!-- ... -->
<textarea id="inputText" rows="5" placeholder="Enter text"></textarea>
<!-- ... -->
<button id="goButton">Go!</button>
<!-- ... -->
```

---

*MainController.java*

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private WebView webDoc;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        final WebEngine webEngine = webDoc.getEngine();
        String url = this.getClass().getResource("/html/main.html").toExternalForm();

        webEngine.load(url);
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {

                final Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();

                EventTarget button = (EventTarget) doc.getElementById("goButton");

                button.addEventListener("click", evt -> {
                    HTMLTextAreaElement textField = (HTMLTextAreaElement) doc.getElementById("inputText");
                    alert(textField.getValue());
                }, false);
            }
        });
    }

    private void alert(String text) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, text);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

---

*Main.java*

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = gecSceneFromXml("/fxml/main.fxml");

        stage.setTitle("New window");
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    private Scene gecSceneFromXml(String fileName) throws java.io.IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
        return new Scene(root);
    }
}
```

---

*main.fxml*

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="500" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.MainController">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="webDoc" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"  prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the solution @Psychokiller1888 gave you? You should mark that answer as correct.

Comment: I just gave my full example. I don't understand why people think that "This answer is not useful" ((

Comment: Because you simply plagiarized the existing answer. None of the additional material you provided was part of the original question, so it doesn't really add anything.