# How to deny access to webpage from javafx web

Tags: java, javafx, webview, kiosk, javafx-webengine

I am currently working on a kiosk project in javafx. It uses WebView/WebEngine. I need to allow the kiosk admin to ban access to certain websites, I know how to check if they match, but how do I hook webengine so that it will tell me when it goes to a page. the kiosk checks it, and then I can redirect it to a blockpage url. How can I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a listener to the [`locationProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#locationProperty--) of the WebView's WebEngine and, within the listener, check if the new location matches your blacklist.

For example (in Java 8):

```
WebEngine engine = webview.getEngine();
engine.locationProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue.contains("badsite")) { // replace with your URL checking logic
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            // Load your block page url
            engine.load("http://example.com"));
        }
    }
});
```

As per [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555877/2647707),  the JVM may crash if the `engine.load()` call is not wrapped in a `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: Does this really ensure that the web page is never loaded? Not even for a short amount of time?

Comment: @mipa Good point. I just checked with Wireshark and this **does not** prevent the HTTP GET request from being sent to the `badsite` server. Whether the WebView will ever display the response, I'm not sure. I'm not aware of any other ways to redirect the webview though, without using a proper firewall/proxy.